# Replace column names with the string that partially match in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with column names `mycolumns` (have more than 2000 columns). I have this obect called `myobject` which contains sets of strings that partially matches with the column names(each matches with only one column name) in `mycolumns`. I want to replace the column names with the respective strings in my object.So the new column names of the dataframe will be `"jackal","cat.11","Rat.Fox"`. Please note this has to be done by using pattern matching or regex as the order of the matched names could be different in myobject.

```
mycolumns <- c("jackal.fox11.FAD", "cat.11.miss.DAD", "Rat.Fox.11.33.DDG")
myobject  <- c("jackal","Rat.Fox","cat.11")
```

Comment: Unless you're trying to do matching via regular expressions, which you don't mention in your question. `names(<data.frame>) <- myobject`

Comment: Yes that has to be pattern matching, because the order could be different.

Comment: You don't describe that in your question. Please revise

Comment: I just did. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a for loop with grep:

```
 #your example
 mycolumns <- c("jackal.fox11.FAD", "cat.11.miss.DAD", "Rat.Fox.11.33.DDG")
 myobject  <- c("jackal","Rat.Fox","cat.11")

 #for loop solution
 for(i in myobject){
      mycolumns[grepl(i, mycolumns)] <- i
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Data setup:

```
> mycols = qw("jackal.fox11.FAD cat.11.miss.DAD Rat.Fox.11.33.DDG")
> df = read.csv(textConnection("1,2,3"), header=F)
> names(df) = qw("jackal Rat.Fox cat.11")
```

The business:

```
> names(df) = sapply(names(df), function(n) mycols[grepl(n, mycols)])
```

The result:

```
> names(df)
[1] "jackal.fox11.FAD"  "Rat.Fox.11.33.DDG" "cat.11.miss.DAD"
```

---

props to @luke-singham for basis of approach

`qw` defined in my `.Rprofile` as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31932661/338303

Comment: You just did exactly opposite of what I need, but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that the names are the same as here, this is quite simple. However, that situation is trivial, so  there doesn't seem to be any value in the solution vs just `names(df) <- myobject`

```
names(df)[c(grep(myobject[1], mycolumns), grep(myobject[2], mycolumns), grep(myobject[3], mycolumns))] <- myobject
```

Comment: This will not work for me, because the dataframe has more than 2000 columns.

Comment: @MAPK if you don't provide a **complete** example of what you're trying to do, then you can't expect to receive a proper solution. I noted in my answer that the solution was trivial. Your question does not describe your **actual** problem.